# How to import Widget class into Qt MainWindow in pyside

Tags: python, pyside

I'd like to define two class in pyside.

The first one:StartFrame is the MainWindow. The second one:HelpPanel is a part of GUI.

I try to import HelpPanel into StartFrame and output it. But the result is an empty window, no HelpPanel in it.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide.QtCore import Signal as pyqtSignal
from PySide.QtCore import Slot as pyqtSlot


class StartFrame(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(StartFrame, self).__init__(parent)  
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
    def initialize(self):
        self.hp = HelpPanel(self)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.hp, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()


class HelpPanel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(HelpPanel,self).__init__(parent)    
        self.parent = parent                      
        bsize = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()                 
        title = QtGui.QLabel('Help Information')    
        text_area = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        text_area.setReadOnly(True)
        bsize.addWidget(title)        
        bsize.addStretch(0)
        bsize.addWidget(text_area)     
        bsize.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(bsize)           
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = StartFrame()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If without StartFrame, the HelpPanel itself can run and get output. I suspect that the problem happens on self.hp = HelpPanel(self). But I'm not sure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why PySide doesn't give a warning, but if you run this code under PyQt you get this message:

```
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on StarteFrame "", which already has a layout
```

The problem is that the `QMainWindow` class comes with its own layout already, and you are trying to overwrite it. One way to overcome this is to place your layout inside a new widget and use [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) to assign it to you instance of `QMainWindow`

Your new `initialize` function would look something like this:

```
    def initialize(self):
        self.hp = HelpPanel(self)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.hp)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.show()
```